# Auto-Layout animation takes center as anchoring point

Tags: ios, swift3, autolayout, ios-animations

I have an height animation based on constraints. However when animation starts it takes view's center as anchoring point not the top.

I want it to animate as fixed top and shrinking from the bottom.

Sorry for my English not a native speaker.

my views anchors:

```
top: superview
left: superview
right: superview
bottom: nil

// current height constant 200
view.height.constant = 0

UIView.animation(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    view.layoutIfNeded()
}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try instead of your view:

```
superView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

this will layout the subview and your animation should work.

so replace

```
    // current height constant 200
view.height.constant = 0

UIView.animation(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    view.layoutIfNeded()
}
```

with

```
    // current height constant 200
yourView.height.constant = 0

UIView.animation(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    yourViewSuperview.layoutIfNeded()
}
```

see layoutIfNeeded() apple docs: [[1]https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)

Comment: Amazing thank you! I was using super.layoutIfNeeded but superview fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change code

```
// current height constant 200
view.height.constant = 0

UIView.animation(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    view.layoutIfNeded()
}}
```

to

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
// current height constant 200
view.height.constant = 0
}}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Its not actually animating but thats okay right now :)

Comment: Its not meeting the needs, sorry. Also changing constant in animate func does nothing btw